# Quickly closing of the confirmation window leads to infinit await of sendTransaction

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I have a next.js project that use @solana/wallet-adapter.

Key parts of client side code:

```
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'
...
const { publicKey, sendTransaction, connected } = useWallet();
...
const response = await fetch(`/api/get-transaction ... `);
const { transaction: base64 } = await response.json();
const serializedTransaction = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');
const transaction = web3.Transaction.from(serializedTransaction);

let txid = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
```

All works fine except single case:

1. User click button an code above started.
2. Transaction gained from server
3. sendTransaction called
4. Confirm transaction window opening (still all is ok).
5. User close it fast, the contents of the popup window are not yet displayed.
6. Done! sendTransaction will not stopped or timeout too big.

I expect error "User rejected the request." like in case when user press cancel or close this window not so fast.

I tested it on Firefox + Phantom Wallet and Chrome + Solflare. Result the same.